# Output in second Activity does not work

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I working on a speech recognition on Android Studio.

***MainActivity.java:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView voiceInput;
    private TextView speakButton;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        voiceInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
        speakButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                askSpeechInput();
            }
        });
    }

    // Showing google speech input dialog

    private void askSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Hi speak something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

        }
    }

    // Receiving speech input

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that you can see that the last part is for the output ***responsible***:

```
    // Receiving speech input


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

***My question*** 
Now I created a second activity and wanted to receive the output there,so I copied these code block above and pasted it. It didn't worked. 

 How can I let the output of my spoken input be in the second activity? 
If you need more information please let me know and sorry for the dumb question, I think the solution is very easy but I couldn't fine them!

Answer (score 0):

Try to send result data into second activity like below code..

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
                Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("result",result);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

and second activity in onCreate method called below line for getting result..

```
result_list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("result");
```

after then result_list data show into textview and other views.

make sure both activity define into android manifest file..

Comment: Hey Android Team! Thank you alot for this response. So I have to paste afterwards the "result_list = ...." at the beginning of the second activity where onCreate starts and then that's it?

Comment: yes after data getting result data you can show that data into textview and log.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass an ArrayList<E> to Your SecondActivity.
```

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("yourlist", yourList);
```

In the other Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> yourList = (ArrayList<String>) 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("yourlist");
```